# identify aws products global or regional list

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to identify all aws services/products which works as global one. Like IAM and S3 console page shows as Global

[image]

Is there any API or commands to get the list of services to identify this global regional support.

Tried with `aws ssm get-parameters --path /aws/service/global-infrastructure/services/s3` but not successful.

Any lead would be appreciated.